# How to compress still image size without quality degrade - easy method

Tags: image, compression

I have high quality photographs with very high `filesize`. I want an easy way to compress any image to lower `filesize` without degrading image quality at all. I have used several DOS `jpg` `png` compressor, online compressor; all of them works but when I have to compress a single image, I find those process too long.

Any easier way to compress `filesize` without shrink or quality-degrade?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a way for myself to compress filesize of still image without shrinking or quality degrade: `mspaint.exe`

1. Open any file with `mspaint.exe` for `windows`. Rightclick file and click `Edit`
2. Just save the file as it is `ctrl + s`
3. That's compressed. Yaay!

Advantages:

- Very fast
- No noticeable quality degrade
- No shrink in imagesize
- Compressed filesize

Comment: Um, you don't seem to understand the least about file formats...